How do I get from integral to computational formula of Cramér-von Mises statistic step by step?
My question is related to the calculus procedures behind Cramér-von Mises test.
How do I get from integral:

to computational formula:

of Cramér-von Mises statistic, step by step?
I understand the logic behind the integral and the statistical aspects of the test, but not the computational formula.

Have you tried the calculation? Related derivation for motivation of a possible approach: Deriving Sample version of Anderson Darling test statistic from the theoretical version.

@User1865345 it helped me a lot. Thanks. my calculus is very basic. I don't understand why the first sumation is from 0 to n-1 and the second one is from 1 to n.

For the first sum, $u_{n+1}$ was taken to be one and so the logarithm would yield zero. For the second sum, for $i=0, $ the first term would be zero.
